# How to combine Background Image + Linear Gradient in CSS ? Linear Gradient over the Background Image

Tags: html, css, web, background, background-image

wish you all are doing well.

So I have a section with a background image and I want to add a linear gradient over the background image.

The result I aim for:
[image]

Till now, I have a div with a background image.

Curent CSS:

```css
background-image: url("../pixels/lastCallToActionBg.jpg");
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Linear Gradiant CSS that I want to add:

```css
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(
  top,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 1%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-gradient(
  linear,
  left top,
  left bottom,
  color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)),
  color-stop(1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)),
  color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)),
  color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))
); /* Chrome4-9,Safari4-5 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
  top,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 1%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(
  top,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 1%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
); /* Opera 11.10-11.50 */ /* IE10 preview */
background: -webkit-gradient(
  linear,
  left top,
  left bottom,
  from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)),
  color-stop(1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)),
  color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)),
  to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))
);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(
  top,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 1%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
);
background: linear-gradient(
  to bottom,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 1%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `div` inside the section, it will serve as a mask, and set the gradient of this mask as a background in it.

The css of the mask will look like this:

```
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

So it would be all over the parent element (section)

```css
section {

    width: 100vw;
    height: 10rem;
    background: url(https://www.yannickdixon.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/161124-golden-seaside-sunset-photography-print.jpg);
}

.overlay {

position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100% );
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) );
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100% );
    background: -o-linear-gradient( top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100% );
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100% );
    background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100% );
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 );
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="overlay"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: I saw you want it compatible with all the browsers, that's why I did it this way, including all your code.

You're welcome.

Comment: Yeah I believe that compatibility is the first thing to look at and it's very important, thanx again.

Answer (score 3):

try this one

```css
body {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://actionseaze.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/sunset.jpg), 
  -webkit-linear-gradient(
    top,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 1%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 35%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
  );
  background-blend-mode: color;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) css psuedo-element to achieve this.

```
body::after{
    content: '';
    linear-gradient(
        top,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 1%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 35%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
  );
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
```